# Can I access the host (OS X) filesystem from the boot2docker VM?

Tags: macos, docker, ibm-cloud

For the sake of the question, lets assume I have the boot2docker VM and I have installed Python (with pip and easysetup), Cloud Foundry and ICE installed.

I am now required to either create or edit a Docker image with artifacts that reside on my host machine, OS X 10.10.3. How can I point to a specific file or even access the host machine's filesystem from boot2docker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you used `Boot2Docker-x.x.x.pkg` for OS X to install Docker, the VM in VirtualBox has already made a file sharing of the `/Users` folder between OS X host and itself. So you can simply use `/Users` in VM as if you are operating in OS X.

If you installed Docker with boot2docker.iso manually, you should add a shared folder by yourself.

Comment: Just to confirm: for `docker` commands, it should suffice to just `boot2docker up` and then be able to use `docker load`, etc... I don't necessarily need to `boot2docker ssh`, correct?

Comment: @IdanAdar Nope, you need to login into `boot2docker VM`, then the `docker` command can connect to docker server locally. What's more, if you want to use `docker` in host machine (OS X) without `boot2docker ssh`, you should change the arguments of docker daemon by adding `-H` option. Now the docker client in OS X can connect to docker server remotely with option `-H <docker server ip>:<port>`.